# Can I get all substrings-1 char of a string with something more efficient than o(n^2)?

Tags: c++, substring, big-o

I want to get all the possible strings-1 character of a string. For examples for the string A13 I will get A1, A3 and 13. I made a function that has a quadratic time complexity and I want to know if there’s a technic that can make it more efficient. This is the code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> generateSubstrings(const std::string& inputString) {
    std::vector<std::string> substrings;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inputString.length(); ++i) {
        std::string substring = inputString.substr(0, i) + inputString.substr(i + 1);
        substrings.push_back(substring);
    }
    return substrings;
}

int main() {
    std::string inputString = "A13";
    std::vector<std::string> result = generateSubstrings(inputString);
    
    for (const std::string& substring : result) {
        std::cout << substring << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use `std::string_view` (in this case, `std::vector<std::string_view>`), rather than constructing all those new strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the output has `O(n^2)` characters, you're not going to be able to output it all in less than `O(n^2)` time. It's possible to emplace the strings, one after the other, into the same buffer in only `O(n)` time total, but that wouldn't be useful because you couldn't consume them in less than `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Okay, yes I get it. Thank you that was my concern.